# syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, что за хрень такая: вставляю класс копипастом - ошибка, пишу в ручную - нет ошибки . 
Заметил, что какие-то отступы имеются и когда их убираешь - все ок.

Как решить проблему? - неужели весь код в ручную переписывать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите hexdump'ом или любым hex-редактором, что именно вы вставляете в файл. Если вы не видите какие-то символ - это не значит, что их там нет. Особенно касаемо юникода, с которым ядро php работает до жути просто и очевидно: игнорирует его существование и работает на уровне байтов, а не символов.

Очевидно, перед ключевым словом `class` копируется что-то, что парсер не понимает как пробельный символ, считает это что-то допустимой лексемой (пока допустимой, вдруг это вызов функции с допустимым именем или ещё что допустимое), а затем видит ключевое слово `class` и очень ему удивляется.